# Laravel not fetching result from mongodb

Tags: php, json, laravel, mongodb, laravel-5

I have a json file called "University.json" which contains only one row of records.

```
{"University": [{"fees": "$200"}, {"month": "June"}]}
```

Now I have used mongo import to insert the above *.json file into MongoDb.

```
mongoimport --db university --collection finance --file University.json
```

My Mongo database/collection values are : university/finance
To show the values on view blade from MongoDb , I have tried as below but not able to show the return result. Also, I have a top level element in my json file which is "University". So, is this the proper way to fetch the nested elements. Please suggest.

## Route (web.php)

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
     Route::get('/finance', 'FeesController@getFees');
});
```

## Controller (FeesController.php)

```
...
public function getFees()
    {
        $fees = Finance::all();
        return view('tables', compact('fees'));
    }
...
```

## Model (Finance.php)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;


class Finance extends Eloquent
{
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $collection = 'finance';

    protected $fillable = [
        'fees', 'month'
    ];
}
```

## View blade (tables.blade.php)

```
<tr>
        <th>fees</th>
        <th>Month</th>
    </tr>

      @foreach($fees as $fee)
      <tr>
        <td>{{$fee->fees}}</td>
        <td>{{$fee->month}}</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
```

## . env file

```
MONGODB_CONNECTION=mongodb
MONGODB_HOST=127.0.0.1
MONGODB_PORT=27017
MONGODB_DATABASE=university
MONGODB_USERNAME=
MONGODB_PASSWORD=
```

## database.php

```
...
    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
        'mongodb' => [
                    'driver'   => 'mongodb',
                    'host'     => env('MONGODB_HOST', 'localhost'),
                    'port'     => env('MONGODB_PORT', 27017),
                    'database' => env('MONGODB_DATABASE', 'university'),
                    'username' => env('MONGODB_USERNAME'),
                    'password' => env('MONGODB_PASSWORD'),
                    'options'  => [
                        'database' => 'admin' // sets the authentication database required by mongo 3
                    ]
                ],

    'mysql' => [
                'driver' => 'mysql',
                'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
                'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
                'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
                'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
                'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
                'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
                'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
                'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
                'prefix' => '',
                'prefix_indexes' => true,
                'strict' => true,
                'engine' => null,
                'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
                ]) : [],
            ],
...
```

## app.php

```
...
/*
    `Mongo DB
    */
    Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider::class,
...
```

Note : I am using both mysql and mongodb for my requirements. There is no issue while attempting simple json structure without top level element.

## Edit (1) :

I have changed the controller function as :

```
public function getFees()
{
$fees = Finance::where(['University.month' => 'June'])->get();
   return view('tables')->with('fees', json_decode($fees, true));
}
```

and simply print the below in view blade shows the entire Json structure from mongo.

```
{!! json_encode($fees) !!}
```

output :

```
[{"_id":"5e04a06ca445f78401a16d0a","University":[{"fees":"$200"},{"month":"June"}]}]
```

But now how to separate the elements ? 
I want to show Fees = $200 and Month = June in the blade view.

I have tried but not working and giving undefined index exception fees in view.

```
@foreach($fees['member'] as $member)
    Fees: {{ $member['University']['fees'] }}
    Month: {{ $member['University']['fees'] }}
@endforeach
```

Final solution shown in another question. may be helpful if someone facing similar situation.

[Laravel : How to split/fetch the json nested elements in blade view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59493934/laravel-how-to-split-fetch-the-json-nested-elements-in-blade-view#59496527)

Comment: Did you configure your `.env` and `database.php` files and set `Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider::class` in `app.php` as provider?

Comment: @mare96 please check my Edit(1) section

Comment: What you get when doing `{!! $fees !!}` I think you don't need `json_encode`. Please provide that.

Comment: @mare96 I am getting Array to string conversion exception if I use {!! $fees !!}. Also if i replace with the answer written by you, I am getting "Undefined index: member". In my original Edit(1) , I have added 'member' but in actual json there is no 'member' element. So, single if()..endif() also throws Undefined index: University.

Comment: Yeah. Try to do in your controller `$fees = Finance::where(['University.month' => 'June'])->get()->toArray();`

Comment: Check my answer now @Abhi

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @mare96 check here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59493934/laravel-how-to-split-fetch-the-json-nested-elements-in-blade-view

Comment: Ok. I will delete my answer then..