# Laravel : How to split/fetch the json nested elements in blade view?

Tags: php, json, laravel, mongodb

When i am passing the below in view blade shows the entire Json structure fetching from mongo.

```
{!! $fees !!}
```

output :

```
[{"_id":"5e04a06ca445f78401a16d0a","University":[{"fees":"$200"},{"month":"June"}]}]
```

Now how to fetch the nested content.I want to show Fees = $200 and Month = June in the blade

Tried like this but result is 'blank' on the blade without any error. Is there any issue with the nested open/closing :[, which is just after 'University:' in the above JSOn input. Please suggest

```
@foreach ($fees as $value)   
    {{$content[] = $value->['University'] }}  
    @foreach ($content as $key)
        <h1>{{ $key['fees'] }}</h1>
        <h1>{{ $key['month'] }}</h1>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

My earlier steps are given here :
[Laravel not fetching result from mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59489292/laravel-not-fetching-result-from-mongodb#)

Edit(1) :

I tried like this so the structure on blade view.

```
<?php
$get_result = json_decode($fees, true);

#$get_result = implode(",", array_flatten($get_result));
#print_r($get_result);
#$get_result2 = json_encode($get_result, true);

echo "</br>";
print_r($get_result)
?>
```

output :

```
Array ([0] => Array ([_id] => 5e04a06ca445f78401a16d0a [University] 
=> Array ([0] => Array ( [fees] => $200 ) [1] => Array ( [month] => June ) )))
```

Also,

```
<?php
echo htmlentities (print_r (json_encode ($fees), true));
?>
```

output:

```
"[{\"_id\":\"5e04a06ca445f78401a16d0a\",
   \"University\":[{\"fees\":\"$200\"},{\"month\":\"June\"}]}]"
```

Also from Controller i tried as below:

```
..
public function getFees()
{

  # database fetch test (with any one of the db query)
  $fees = Finance::all();

  $fees = Finance::where(['University.month' => 'June'])->get()->toArray();

  $fees = Finance::where('University.month', 'June')->first();

  $fees = Finance::where('University.month', 'June')->get();


  # Return test (with any one of the return)
  return view('tables')->with('fees', json_encode($fees, true));

  return view('tables', compact('fees'));

  return view('tables')->with(compact('fees'));

  return view('tables')->with('fees', $fees);

 }
  ..
```

Edit(2) :

in view blade i tried as below but getting exception as : Trying to get property 'fees' of non-object

```
<?php
$fees = json_decode($fees, true); 
#echo "</br>";
#print_r($fees)
?>

    @foreach ($fees[0] as $value)   
    @php $content = $value->University @endphp  // or without @
    @foreach ($content as $key)
        <h1>{{ $key['fees'] }}</h1>
        <h1>{{ $key['month'] }}</h1>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Edit(3) as per suggestion by Chandan.

```
<?php

$fees = json_decode($fees); 
$univ = $fees[0]->University; 
//print_r($univ); 

foreach ($univ as $key => $value) 
{ 
foreach($univ[$key] AS $k =>$v)
{ 
echo $k." " .$v; 
} 
}
?>
```

output :

```
 fees $200month June
```

only thing the output is merges without comma separated.
Can I show them as below

fees = $200
month = June

or  as a html

```
<td>{{$k}}</td><td>{{$v}}</td>
```

Comment: well with "$value->University" instead of '$value->['University']'? what are you trying to do has no sense

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia yes that code is wrong one. It's not able to find the elements

Comment: try with $value->University

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia it's showing Trying to get property 'University' of non-object error

Comment: and so this should work.. "$value['University']"

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Now it's throwing, trying to get property 'fees' of non-object error, So when i changes {{ $key['fees'] }} , no error but blank value. Or I tried with {{ $key['University.fees'] }}, but same blank result

Comment: to access the fees you have to do '$value['University'][0]->fees' but i think it's not a great way to manage it... check the answer

Comment: Have you tried `json_decode($fees, true)`? If it's printing out in the rendered page the way it's shown in "output:" then it seems like it's not a PHP array yet but a string containing JSON.

Comment: @DavidKanenwisher please check my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$fees = json_decode($fees);
$univ = $fees[0]->University;
//print_r($univ);
foreach ($univ as $key => $value) {
  foreach($univ[$key] as $k =>$v){
     echo $k .'= '.$v.' ';
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not working. Please see my edit for more info.

Comment: use json_decode for $fees = json_decode($fees, true); and foreach($fees[0] as $value) try this

Comment: php $content = $value->University endphp  because $fees[0] is object

Comment: Showing Trying to get property 'fees' of non-object. I tried like this Edit(2)

Comment: $fees = json_decode($fees);
$univ = $fees[0]->University;
//print_r($univ);
foreach ($univ as $key => $value) {
  foreach($univ[$key] AS $k =>$v){
    echo $k." " .$v;
  }
}  this will work

Comment: Many thanks. See my Edit(3) for the output. Also can you change your original answer, so that I can make it 'accepted' .

Answer (score 0):

It should be working as below:-

```
@foreach ($fees as $value)   
    {{$content[] = $value->['University'] }} 

    @if($content->['fees']!==null)
        <h1>{{ $content['fees'] }}</h1>
    @else
        <h1>-</h1>
    @endif

    @if($content->['fees']!==null)
        <h1>{{ $content['fees'] }}</h1>
    @else
        <h1>-</h1>
    @endif

@endforeach
```

Comment: This is not working. Please see my edit for more info.